# Unable to uninstall MikTeX from Windows 10

Tags: miktex, installing

On my Windows 10 machine, I went to `Control panel-->Uninstall a Program`. And went through following Wizard screens but nothing happens. The MiKTeX is still there. I need to uninstall it and then do a fresh install since it is not quit working the way it used to work before. I also tried going to uninstall_admin.exe and uninstall.exe inside C:\Program Files (x86)\MikTeX\miktex\bin\internal\ folder and ran with `As Administrator` but nothing happens:

[image: First Step]
[image: Second Step]
[image: Final step]

**UPDATE**:

After I clicked the `Finish` button on the third screenshot above, the MikTeX is still there. I've even rebooted the system and checked the following:

1. MikTeX program is still in Windows' Control Panel's `Uninstall Program` window.
2. All the MikTeX files are still in `C:\Program Files (x86)\MikTeX\..` folder
3. All the MikTeX utilities (Program Manager, TexWorks etc...) are still in the Start Menu of window and I can open and run them.
4. Only thing I have noticed is that after running the Uninstall wizard below and rebooting the machine, the file association of `.text` file is gone but I can still run `TexWorks` and open a `.tex` file from there. The right pane of the TexWorks displays the Math equations correctly; but when I run the `typeset` button on the top left task bar of left pane I get the following error.

**Error**

```
31 [0x00001eac] INFO initexmf null - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility (MiKTeX 2.9.6100)

46 [0x00001eac] INFO initexmf null - Creating fndb for user root directory (C:\Users\TestUser\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9)...

62 [0x00001eac] INFO initexmf null - Creating fndb for user root directory (C:\Users\TestUser\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9)...

109 [0x00001eac] INFO initexmf null - Skipping common root directory (C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9)...

109 [0x00001eac] INFO initexmf null - Skipping common root directory ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9")...

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9.6100)
log4cxx: No appender could be found for logger (pdflatex).
log4cxx: Please initialize the log4cxx system properly.

Sorry, but "C:\Program Files (x86)\MikTeX\miktex\bin\pdflatex.EXE" did not succeed.

log4cxx: No appender could be found for logger (texify).
log4cxx: Please initialize the log4cxx system properly.

Sorry, but "C:\Program Files (x86)\MikTeX\miktex\bin\texify.exe" did not succeed.
```

Comment: how you know, that the MikTeX is still there?  with this you removed MikTeX (after clicking on "finish").

Comment: these `roaming` files are just residuals. As @nam mentioned above, once you click `finish` uninstallation is completed.

Comment: @Zarko I've added an **UPDATE** section to my post above to answer your question.

Comment: @Yorgos Even after clicking the Finish button, MikTeX is still there. I've added an `UPDATE`section to my post above to add more details.

Comment: than check, if you have installed two MikTeX. anyway, you can install new version of MikTeX in parallel to existing. only you have to take a care for links.

Comment: @Zarko There is only one installation of MikTeX on my machine and only one is showing in Start Menu of Windows. Installing a new version in parallel may cause some other issues in future. Is there any other way to get rid of the existing one first?

Comment: @Zarkoyou can use wise uninstaller. It's an open-source software that handles uninstall procedures more efficient than build-in windows approach

Comment: @Zarko also these "issues" posted in the update are just shortcuts. For instance, it happened for other software as well (for 1). Also note that texwork is an independent application and it has nothing to do with miktex (texworks comes also with texlive). The error you get confirms that miktex has been uninstalled successfully